# ProvideEmphasis not found in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating all my jetpack compose that has been in an old library version to the new Beta01 , I got this problem when trying to migrate

[image]

where ProvideEmphasis(EmphasisAmbient...) is an unresolved reference, what is the equivalent now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Emphasis` ambient has been replaced with the `ContentAlpha` ambient a bit back: https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/Idf03e63a3082842e183535b5fdbf04947e3a671c

The `Provide...` pattern has been replaced with `CompositionLocalProvider` in the meantime:

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
        Text(...)
}
```

Check out the official samples for content alpha: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/samples/ContentAlphaSamples.kt